# Magento Magmi Import Tool - Not importing products into specified store/category root

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I have a Magento CE 1.8.1 website

It contains 2 stores, with a root category assigned to each (US and AU)
I want the final structure to look something like:

```
- US (Root cat)
  - Tops  
- AU (Root cat)
  - Bottoms
```

I am trying to import a simple product belonging to category "Tops", within the US store. 
Nothing I try seems to work - "Tops" always gets placed in the AU category.

ATTEMPT 1 (not all CSV fields are listed):

```
sku,name,store,categories
xxx,yyyy,us,Tops
```

This produces:

```
- US (Root cat)
- AU (Root cat)
  - Tops
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
sku,name,store,categories
xxx,yyyy,us,US/Tops
```

This produces:

```
- US (Root cat)
- AU (Root cat)
  - US
    - Tops
```

ATTEMPT 3

```
sku,name,store,categories
xxx,yyyy,us,[US]/Tops
```

This produces:

```
- US (Root cat)
- AU (Root cat)
  - [US]
    - Tops
```

No error message appears - it just seems to fall back to placing the category and product into the last Root category

I have On the fly category creator/importer v0.2.4 and 
Image attributes processor v1.0.27 utils ticked.

Can anyone advise what I might be doing wrong?
I am using Magmi version v0.7.19_git

Comment: Have you tried setting up a few manually within magento, then export the content frpm magento. That should help you see the syntax you should be importing.

Comment: Great idea.. I'll take a look and report back

Comment: When I exported the existing data, Magento keeps a column titled _root_category which indicates my root items are definitely US and AU. There doesn't seem to be a seperate column for the root category in Magmi - the documentation says to use the 'categories' column, using the format [root category]/... before the category path. This is not working for me however. Completely stuck on this one.

Comment: Have you tried adding that column to your Magmi csv file? That's how I've found out the various columns to put in a Magmi file. Otherwise, I have my categories all under `main` so when I specify `category/subcategory` it all comes under main as `main>category>subcategory`. Could you maybe use that structure?

Comment: update to latest git version, a bug has been fixed for multistore support in categories plugin

Comment: O really Dweeves?! THANK YOU... That is the best news I have heard all day :))) THanks for all your work on this tool.